# MATLAB R2016a - geoshow after contourf (used to work with R2012a)

Tags: matlab

In the past I had Matlab R2012a version, and I used geoshow to plot the land on top of a contourf plot that I made using the code below:

```
contourf(long,lat,conf(:,:,i),[valoneS(i) valtwoS(i)])
```

where i is just a time index and valoneS and valtwoS are the two values that define where I want the 2 contours to be placed.
After contourf I would use geoshow like that:

```
load coastline.mat; levels = [S.Level]; terre = (levels==1);
geoshow(S(terre),'FaceColor', [0.65,0.65,0.65])
```

This used to work. The problem is that since I switched to Matlab R2016a, when I plot the land "`S(terre)`" using geoshow, the map extends to the entire North America, or tow the entire world if I use `geoshow('landareas.shp', 'FaceColor', [0.65 0.65 0.65])` instead on staying focused on my region defined by `long` and `lat` in `contourf`.

Any idea of why this happens and how I could fix it. Thanks. Arno.

Comment: Can you just adjust the axes limits after calling `geoshow`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually specify the displayed region by specifying [the x and y limits of the `axes` object](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#property_XLim).

```
set(gca, 'XLim', [min(long(:)), max(long(:))], ...
         'YLim', [min(lat(:)), max(lat(:))])
```

Comment: I was simpler than I expected. Thanks!